# CloudKit CKSubscription, subscriptionID

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I am trying to study CloudKit and I saw this. https://github.com/ghvillasboas/CloudKitTest

After I have followed that instruction, I can run app and save, fetch data.

However, I saw this code

```
CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc]
                                initWithRecordType:GVCloudKitRecordType predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"] subscriptionID:GVCloudKitSubscriptionId options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];
```

GVCloudKitSubscriptionId = br.com.cocoaheads.cloudkittest.newHeroSubscription for that one. But, for me, how can I create subscriptionID? May I know from where I can register that or get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own subscriptionID. Just remember that ID so that you can also unregister. Create a logical ID. Something like "all" if you are using a true predicate.

Comment: Does a subscription ID have to be unique across all devices for a single iCloud account?

Comment: Good question. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can use the same subscription ID on different devices and those would still be separate predicates.

Comment: For reference I have been doing this for a few weeks in development and haven't had any issues.